# Interactive Transition : Segue declaration

Tags: ios, swift, segue, interactive, transition

Theoretical question : in the code below, why, at the line of "performSegue....", the segue is not performed entirely ? I mean, how it know it's an interactive transition, and why the method "performSegue..." has not the same effect as if she was declared somewhere else ?

### FirstViewController.swift

```
let transitionManager = TransitionManager()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    transitionManager.sourceViewController = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    let dest = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
    dest.transitioningDelegate = transitionManager
    transitionManager.destViewController = dest

}
```

### Storyboard

The segue is from the FirstViewController to the SecondViewController.

- Identifier : "segueIdentifier"
- Segue : Modal
- Destination : Current

### TransitionManager.swift

```
class TransitionManager: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition,UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate,UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning {

    var interactive = false
    var presenting = false

    var panGesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer!

    var sourceViewController : UIViewController! {
        didSet {

            panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "gestureHandler:")
            sourceViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

        }
    }


    func gestureHandler(pan : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = pan.translationInView(pan.view!)

        let d =  translation.x / pan.view!.bounds.width * 0.5        

        switch pan.state {

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began :

            interactive = true

            sourceViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier", sender: self)


        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed :

            self.updateInteractiveTransition(d)

        default :

            interactive = false

            if d > 0.2 || velocity.x > 0 {
                self.finishInteractiveTransition()
            }
            else {
                self.cancelInteractiveTransition()
            }
        }

    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        //Something....


        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {

            //Something....

            }, completion: {}

        })

    }

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 1
    }

    // MARK: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocol methods

    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.presenting = true
        return self
    }

    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.presenting = false
        return self
    }

    func interactionControllerForPresentation(animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return self.interactive ? self : nil
    }

    func interactionControllerForDismissal(animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return self.interactive ? self : nil
    }





}
```

In fact, I have a lot of codes similar to this, this one is working but others very similar do precisely what I was explaining : the segue is just executed without interactive transition. Can someone explain me ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you clarify precisely what the question is? Is your interactive transition animation not being interactive? What precisely is going wrong? What did you expect and what did you experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is that your interactive transition animation is not being interactive, I'd suggest putting a breakpoint in `interactionControllerForPresentation`:

- Make sure that the correct instance of `interactionControllerForPresentation` is called like you think it should be.

  For example, make sure that `viewDidLoad` of destination didn't replace the `transitioningDelegate` that you so carefully set in the `prepareForSegue` in the source controller ... this is easy to do if doing interactive transition from A to B and then again from B to C, what you set up in anticipation to B to C can interfere with what you intended to do from A to B.
- Make sure that `interactionControllerForPresentation` is returning the value that you think it should (i.e. make sure that `interactive` is definitely `true`).

Every time I've seen this behavior of a gesture not initiating the transition interactively, like I think it should, it has been because when `interactionControllerForPresentation` was called in the destination controller's `transitioningDelegate`, it didn't return a valid  `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning` (such as a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`) like I intended it to.

Anyway, you can diagnose this by adding a log statement in `interactionControllerForPresentation`, and you'll either see that (a) it's not called for some reason; or (b) `self.interactive` is not `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem is that I don't really understand what I'm doing when using interactive transition. I tried to put prinln() everywhere, and what I don't understand is the chronology : which function is called, when ? Indeed, with the println(), the problem is that self.interactive is not true here, but it was true just before, in the prepareForSegue function, and is true after, in the gestureHandler function. It's false just for the function... You seems to know a lot about interactive transition, do you know a tutorial or something which explain nicely how does it work ? Thx

Comment: In terms of good demo, I used the WWDC video and little experimentation. I'm sure there are good demos out there, but I just don't have one to recommend. But googling "iOS custom transition tutorial" gave me lots of promising hits. In terms of why `interactive` is not true, I might guess that although source is instantiating `TransitionManager`, maybe `viewDidLoad` of destination view controller is instantiating another? I don't know. Hard to say without seeing more code. Personally, I might prefer to see the destination own this object rather than the source controller.

Comment: I finally solved the problem, don't ask me how... Thanks for your help, I'm going to search for the WWDC videos.